# Run a python script before Building/Running the android application

Tags: android, python

I have a python script that I want to run before I do the "Run As -> Android Application" in Eclipse.  Currently it shows me these errors.

```
Errors running builder 'Integrated External Tool Builder' on project 'exampleProject'.
Exception occurred executing command line.
Cannot run program "/Users/mdur/Documents/workspace/exampleProject/res/Swap.py": error=13, Permission denied
Exception occurred executing command line.
Cannot run program "/Users/mdur/Documents/workspace/exampleProject/res/Swap.py": error=13, Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

Which OS are you using? On Linux, `Permission denied` often means that you should run the command with `sudo` - `sudo do this command` rather than `do this command`.

Comment: I am Using OSx Yosemite. I tried using the sudo command also. but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Is Swap.py executable? If not, try setting it with +x permissions using the Terminal:

```
sudo chmod +x /Users/mdur/Documents/workspace/exampleProject/res/Swap.py
```

Comment: Sadly, its not an executable. Is there any other way to workaround this?

Comment: You make script files executable by setting the +x attribute in a terminal.

Comment: Did you try to make it executable?

Comment: Hi Martin, Did you fix the issue? I too am getting same error. I have permissions set as "-rwxr-xr-x" but still does not work. Any idea?